# curl: continue and remote-header-name cannot be used together?

Tags: curl

I am using curl with both `-C -` and `--remote-name --remote-header-name`.
If the file exists, I get an error that the existing file cannot be overwritten.

Is there a way to work around this? I think this is not an uncommon use case?

// Edit:
I want to resume downloading the file.

Answer (score 2):

`curl` may support skipping files when used with both `-O` and `-J`,
but its behavior is inconsistent.

The `-J` (`--remote-header-name`) option basically tells the
`-O` (`--remote-name`) option to use the server-specified `Content-Disposition`
filename instead of extracting a filename from the URL.
`Curl` then doesn't know what file name the server will return and it may ignore the existing file as a safety precaution.

However, the behavior is unpredictable and it doesn't work for all files.

You may find more information and possible workarounds in the post
[How to skip already existing files when downloading with curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856351/how-to-skip-already-existing-files-when-downloading-with-curl)

Comment: It seems I forgot to write down what I actually want: resume downloading the file, not skipping it.